# Сортировка по датам

Tags: powershell

Необходимо сортировать даты в массиве (на примере ниже). Эти даты считываются из CSV файла в формате string. Из-за этого сортировка работает некорректно (как потом узнал). Решил конвертировать строку в тип Дату но сделать это не так легко как оказалось, так как для функции [datetime]::ParseExact требуется строгий формат вплоть до количества знаков. Тем не менее функция Get-Date $date -Format F ест всё подряд без особых претензий (с пробелами, разными делителями и т.п.) Короче, как наиболее лаконичным способом отсортировать даты ниже, приведя если нужно всё к единому формату. (у меня возникла идея - скормить эти даты сперва функции Get-Date, раз она не требовательна, а потом уже конвертировать как-то даты в тип Date. Но как - не знаю. А может это неправильно).

```
$date1 = '22.11.2018 10:06:56'
$date2 = '26.11.2018 2:06:56'
$date3 = '02.12.2018 01:06:56'

Get-Date $date -Format F

[datetime]::ParseExact($date,”dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss”,$null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
('22.11.2018 10:06:56', '21.11.2018 2:06:56', '2.2.2018 01:06:56') | % {[datetime]::ParseExact(([regex]::split($_, '\D+') | % {$_.padLeft(2, '0')}) -join '-', 'dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss', $null)} | sort
```

Comment: #### ух. класс ##